# wordpress saving blank custom posts when removing title, excerpt or editor

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I notice that whenever I remove either the title, editor or excerpt support from a custom post type, and I save a custom post without entering any information, it shows up in the custom post type’s ‘all posts’ overview, using (no title) as title. If title, editor and excerpt support are all used, posts with no content seems to be discarded by wordpress.

On itself that’s not really a problem. One should simply not save a post without entering any info, and if it does happen by accident the (no title) line can be removed from the posts overview in the admin.

However, I created a custom post type that uses additional form validation (preg_match) for certain meta fields. If these preg_matches fail, the post isn’t saved, but in stead the user gets some custom error messages while the entered data is saved in transients for display back to the user.

It now happens, that whenever a users enters some information that doesn’t pass the preg_match check, the lack of support for title, editor and excerpt fields cause the post to be saved anyway. None of the input information is stored, so it’s just a blank post but it shows up as a blank line in the columns of the all posts overview.

It can easily be solved by adding support for title, editor and excerpt, but I do not want those in my custom post type.

It seems wordpress checks wether or not there is data entered in those fields, and if no data is entered in any of them, it simply discards the post while saving. But if the fields are not there at all, they can’t be checked and the post is stored anyway?

Any ideas to get rid of this problem?

Here's an image of what I mean exactely:

[blank line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRVMk.jpg)

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you shared the part of your code that handles validation. I have created custom post types without editor and excerpt support in the past without issues when using custom validation logic. I have not tried without a title though. Have you tried adding support for just the title and using that field somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on this on the wordpress forum:

[wordpress-saving-blanks-custom-posts-when-removing-title-excerpt-or-editor](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-saving-blanks-custom-posts-when-removing-title-excerpt-or-editor/)

The behavior you refer to that discards empty posts if title and other field support exist is managed by the “wp_insert_post_empty_content” filter. If you hook this filter, you can make any other checks you like. If your custom fields are not in the passed post array (second argument), the data should still be in $_POST.

Since you don’t have title and the other usual support, a false value will always be passed as the first argument. All your callback needs to do is return true and the post save is aborted and a WP_Error object is returned from the wp_insert_post() call.